# How to remove rows from a dataframe based on keyword found in a particular columns in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a dataframe for devices against the various userId:

df=

| userId | userDisplayName | devicename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A12345 | Ronaldo | L-15672727 |
| B23456 | Ibrahimovic | DR27365_Android_1/1/2019_5:31 PM |
| C34567 | Messi | Messi’s Iphone |
| D45678 | Benncer | realmeRMX2001 |
| E56789 | Leao | XiaomiRedmi Note 8 Pro |
| F67890 | Theo | A-android |
| G67890 | Calabria | Davide's iphone |
| H67890 | Tonali | REALME_TON |
| I67890 | Giroud | 12348475androidgiroud |

Now I want to remove all the mobile devices from dataframe. That means I want to remove all 'devicename' containing "Android", "iPhone","Realme","Xiaomi","Redmi".

Finally my output should be:

| userId | userDisplayName | devicename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A12345 | Ronaldo | L-15672727 |

I have tried the following code:
'''
 `df_output=df.where(~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%android%") |         ~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%iphone%") |  ~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%desktop%") | ~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%google%") | ~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%home%") |  ~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%oneplus%") | ~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%realme%") | ~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%samsung%") | ~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%xiaomi%") | ~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%redmi%") | ~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%note%") | ~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%vivo%") | ~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%nokia%") | ~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%moto%"))`
'''

---

However, since spark is case sensative, I am not able to remove all the rows containing these values.

Please help!

Comment: https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/notes/chap14/ch14_21.html

Comment: `not(A or B)` is equivalent to `not A and not B`

Comment: Thanks Steven. This was a learning for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use regex like to avoid repeating statement multiple times

```
 df.filter(~lower.col('devicename').rlike('android|iphone|realme|xiaomi|redmi')).show()
```

Comment: with all lower case, this answer would be great ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace you **OR** (pipes `|`) with **AND** `&`, or simply chain the `where` :

```py
df_output = (
    df.where(~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%android%"))
    .where(~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%iphone%"))
    .where(~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%desktop%"))
    .where(~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%google%"))
    .where(~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%home%"))
    .where(~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%oneplus%"))
    .where(~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%realme%"))
    .where(~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%samsung%"))
    .where(~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%xiaomi%"))
    .where(~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%redmi%"))
    .where(~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%note%"))
    .where(~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%vivo%"))
    .where(~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%nokia%"))
    .where(~f.lower(col("devicename")).like("%moto%"))
)
```

```
df_output.show()

+------+---------------+----------+
|userId|userDisplayName|devicename|
+------+---------------+----------+
|A12345|        Ronaldo|L-15672727|
+------+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this. This worked by replacing 'or (|)' with 'AND (&)' . Grateful for quick support buddy!

Comment: This answer not advisable. Computationally expensive, hard to debug and can make the script very long. Please don't code like this.